# How to contact whole text from file into the string avoiding empty lines beetwen strings

Tags: c#, string, text-processing

How to get whole text from document contacted  into the string. I'm trying to split text by dot: `string[] words = s.Split('.');`  I want take this text from text document. But if my text document contains empty lines between strings, for example:

```
pat said, “i’ll keep this ring.” 

she displayed the silver and jade wedding ring which, in another time track, 
she and joe had  picked  out;  this  

much  of the  alternate  world  she  had  elected to retain. he wondered what - if any - legal basis she had  kept  in  addition.  none,  he  hoped;  wisely,  however,  he  said nothing. better not even to ask.
```

result looks like this:

```
1. pat said ill keep this ring
2. she displayed the silver and jade wedding ring which in another time track
3. she and joe had  picked  out  this
4. much  of the  alternate  world  she  had  elected to retain
5. he wondered what  if any  legal basis she had  kept  in  addition
6. none  he  hoped  wisely  however  he  said nothing
7. better not even to ask
```

but desired correct output should be like this:

```
1. pat said ill keep this ring
2. she displayed the silver and jade wedding ring which in another time track she and joe had  picked  out  this much  of the  alternate  world  she  had  elected to retain
3. he wondered what  if any  legal basis she had  kept  in  addition
4. none  he  hoped  wisely  however  he  said nothing
5. better not even to ask
```

So to do this first I need to process text file content to get whole text as single string, like this:

```
pat said, “i’ll keep this ring.” she displayed the silver and jade wedding ring which, in another time track, she and joe had  picked  out;  this much  of the  alternate  world  she  had  elected to retain. he wondered what - if any - legal basis she had  kept  in  addition.  none,  he  hoped;  wisely,  however,  he  said nothing. better not even to ask.
```

I can't to do this same way as it would be with list content for example: `string concat = String.Join(" ", text.ToArray());`,

I'm not sure how to contact text into string from text document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
var fileLocation = @"c:\\myfile.txt";
var stringFromFile = File.ReadAllText(fileLocation);

//replace Environment.NewLine with any new line character your file uses
var withoutNewLines = stringFromFile.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "");

//modify to remove any unwanted character          
var withoutUglyCharacters = Regex.Replace(withoutNewLines, "[“’”,;-]", "");
var withoutTwoSpaces = withoutUglyCharacters.Replace("  ", " ");

var result = withoutTwoSpaces.Split('.').Where(i => i != "").Select(i => i.TrimStart()).ToList();
```

So first you read all text from your file, then you remove all unwanted characters and then split by `.` and return non empty items

Comment: You are assuming that the file will use the same newline characters as the machine. This will fail on Windows with files that use `\n`

Comment: Yes, that depends on specific file. But it is not a problem to replace `Environment.NewLine` with new line character that is used in file.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried replacing double new-lines before splitting using a period?

```
static string[] GetSentences(string filePath) {
        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
            throw new FileNotFoundException($"Could not find file { filePath }!");

        var lines = string.Join("", File.ReadLines(filePath).Where(line => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(line) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)));

        var sentences = Regex.Split(lines, @"\.[\s]{1,}?");

        return sentences;
    }
```

I haven't tested this, but it should work.

---

Explanation:

> if (!File.Exists(filePath))
>                   throw new FileNotFoundException($"Could not find file { filePath }!");

Throws an exception if the file could not be found. It is advisory you surround the method call with a try/catch.

> var lines = string.Join("", File.ReadLines(filePath).Where(line => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(line) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)));

Creates a string, and ignores any lines which are purely whitespace or empty.

> var sentences = Regex.Split(lines, @".[\s]{1,}?");

Creates a string array, where the string is split at every period and whitespace following the period.

E.g:

The string "I came. I saw.   I conquered" would become

1. I came
2. I saw
3. I conquered

**Update:**

Here's the method as a one-liner, if that's your style?

```
static string[] SplitSentences(string filePath) => File.Exists(filePath) ? Regex.Split(string.Join("", File.ReadLines(filePath).Where(line => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(line) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))), @"") : null;
```

Comment: IsNullOrWhitespace also checks for empty strings. You don't need `IsNullOrEmpty`

Comment: This will produce string that contains `"` or `,`. In the example output these were not present so I assume this method fails.

Comment: @m.rogalski No, I don't think it would. Empty lines are filtered out before separating via period and whitespace. 
And even so, a simple .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)) would do the trick.

Comment: @Beatsleigher You don't have to think. Just check it. I've checked all answers here and then I've posted the same comment on each invalid answer.

Comment: @m.rogalski Being rude is mildly inappropriate. Tested the code, works fine, but thanks for your concern. 
Results here: http://pastebin.com/w8ubU7SY

Comment: @Beatsleigher I'm not rude. Just [check your code before posting](http://rextester.com/YJWJ72719). Even your pastebin shows that I'm right

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to iterate through all characters and just check if they are in range of `'a' >= char <= 'z'` or if `char == ' '`. If it matches the condition then add it to the newly created string else check if it is `'.'` character and if it is then end your line and add another one :

```
List<string> lines = new List<string>();
string line = string.Empty;
foreach(char c in str)
{
    if((char.ToLower(c) >= 'a' && char.ToLower(c) <= 'z') || c == 0x20)
        line += c;
    else if(c == '.')
    {
        lines.Add(line.Trim());
        line = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

[Working online example](http://rextester.com/MWEGQ49937)

Or if you prefer "one-liner"s :

```
IEnumerable<string> lines = new string(str.Select(c => (char)(((char.ToLower(c) >= 'a' && char.ToLower(c) <= 'z') || c == 0x20) ? c : c == '.' ? '\n' : '\0')).ToArray()).Split('\n').Select(s => s.Trim());
```

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong about this. I would think that you may not want to alter the string if you are splitting it. Example, there are double/single quote(s) (“) in part of the string. Removing them may not be desired which brings up the possibly of a question, reading a text file that contains single/double quotes (as your example data text shows) like below:

```
var stringFromFile = File.ReadAllText(fileLocation);
```

will not display those characters properly in a text box or the console because the default encoding using the `ReadAllText` method is UTF8. Example the single/double quotes will display (replacement characters) as diamonds in a text box on a form and will be displayed as a question mark (?) when displayed to the console. To keep the single/double quotes and have them display properly you can get the encoding for the OS’s current ANSI encoding by adding a parameter to the `ReadAllText` method like below:

```
string stringFromFile = File.ReadAllText(fileLocation, ASCIIEncoding.Default);
```

Below is code using a simple split method to .split the string on periods (.) Hope this helps.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  string fileLocation = @"C:\YourPath\YourFile.txt";
  string stringFromFile = File.ReadAllText(fileLocation, ASCIIEncoding.Default);
  string bigString = stringFromFile.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "");
  string[] result = bigString.Split('.');
  int count = 1;
  foreach (string s in result) {
    if (s != "") {
      textBox1.Text += count + ". " + s.Trim() + Environment.NewLine;
      Console.WriteLine(count + ". " + s.Trim());
      count++;
    }
    else {
      // period at the end of the string
    }
  }
}
```